# Update Panel from different Panel in Wicket

Tags: wicket

In Wicket I have a Site that contains two `Panels`:

```
<body>
    <wicket:panel>
        <div wicket:id="menu"></div>
        <div wicket:id="content"></div>
    </wicket:panel>
</body>
```

The `menu-Panel` generates `links` inside a `ListView`:

```
//inside menuPanel.java
@Override
protected void populateItem(ListItem<Link> link) {
    final WebMarkupContainer categoryMenuItemLink = new WebMarkupContainer("categoryMenuItemLink");
    link.add(categoryMenuItemLink);
    link.add(new AjaxEventBehavior("click") {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            System.out.println("Ajax works");
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see each `link` is added a `AjaxEventBehavior`. My Problem is now that I cant access the `content-Panel` to update its content.
So what I'am looking for is something like this:

```
 // inside menuPanel.java
 @Override
protected void populateItem(ListItem<Link> link) {
    final WebMarkupContainer categoryMenuItemLink = new WebMarkupContainer("categoryMenuItemLink");
    link.add(categoryMenuItemLink);
    link.add(new AjaxEventBehavior("click") {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            System.out.println("Ajax works");
            //Panel p = getPanel("content);
            //p.update(newContent);
            //target.add(p);
        }
    });
}
```

Each `Panel` is in a different `class`:

- menuPanel.java
- contentPanel.java

Comment: Although you find the solution to this problem. I would suggest `broadcast` event if the components are in different class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make you panel abstract and define abstract method:

```
abstract Panel getContentPanel();
```

And when you will add panels on your Page you need to implement abtsract method:

```
Panel contentPanel = new ConentPanel();
Panel menuPanel = new MenuPanel() {
    @Override
    Panel getContentPanel() {
        return contentPanel;
    }
}
```

And now in event's you can get contentPanel

Answer (score 1):

inside your event handler you can use `findParent(OuterPanel.class)` where OuterPanel.class is the panel you describe at the beginning of your question (i.e. the one containing menu and content panel). 
Once you have it you can get content panel with `outerPanel.get("content")`

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, unfortunately everytime I access the panel it is null

Answer (score 1):

As soorapadman commented, you should use events for your problem to maintain the separation between the components (testing, reusability etc.).
In the Wicket [examples](http://examples7x.wicket.apache.org/wicket-examples/index.html) you find a short [demonstration](http://examples7x.wicket.apache.org/wicket-examples/events/). I borrowed their [code](http://examples7x.wicket.apache.org/wicket-examples/events/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.source.SourcesPage?0&SourcesPage_class=org.apache.wicket.examples.events.IndexPage) to adapt it to your problem:

A "payload" for your event, which is in this case a simple wrapper class with a AjaxRequest to help us update the content.

```
    public class ContentUpdate {
        private final AjaxRequestTarget target;

        public CounterUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            this.target = target;
        }

        public AjaxRequestTarget getTarget() {
            return target;
        }
    }
```

And your menuPanel class

```
//inside menuPanel.java
@Override
protected void populateItem(ListItem<Link> link) {
  final WebMarkupContainer categoryMenuItemLink = new 
  WebMarkupContainer("categoryMenuItemLink");
  link.add(categoryMenuItemLink);
  link.add(new AjaxEventBehavior("click") {          

      @Override
      protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
          send(getPage(), Broadcast.BREADTH, new ContentUpdate(target));
      }
   });
}
```

Your content panel now should override the onEvent method to receive the event "message".

```
 //inside contentPanel.java
    @Override
    public void onEvent(IEvent<?> event) {
        super.onEvent(event);

        // check if this is a counter update event and if so repaint self
        if (event.getPayload() instanceof ContentUpdate) {
            ContentUpdate update = (ContentUpdate)event.getPayload();
            // Do some stuff ...
            update.getTarget().add(this);
        }
    }
```